# Number of possible boards without given patterns

Tags: algorithm

I try to invent some dynamic algorithm, to solve the given problem:

We have a board with 5 rows and `n` columns. Each field can be coloured with black or white colour (1 or 0).

Someone gave us up to 5 patterns. Each pattern size is 3x3. E.g. this can be a pattern:

```
...
.x.   // We got 1 black field in the middle
...
```

Our task is to **give a number of all possible boards colouring that doesn't contain even single appearance of any pattern**.

My initial idea was to scan whole board with *`window`* of size 5x2 (5 rows and 2 colums), but I don't see any way to do it right.

Comment: Can a pattern wrap?  E.g. can a pattern begin in the `n`th column and continue into the first column?

Comment: Tim, patterns cannot wrap

Comment: ERRATA: There are only 5 patterns. Mistyped between windows, sorry!

Comment: Put the patterns into a hash set so you can do the comparison quickly. Then you can use a recursive backtracking algorithm to go over the possible patterns. In each recursive call there are two possible numbers you can put into the current field (0 or 1). For both options you check all the 3x3 windows that contain the current field to see if any of them are contained in the set of patterns.

Comment: If it's only 5 patterns a hash set may not be the fastest option.

Comment: Pola: it's from polish site, I translated it.

Comment: Spider, won't that be too slow? I mean, we need to generate all that kind of boards.

Comment: Additional thing I thought about is counting all bad boards instead of good ones. It seems to be much more good boards than bad.

Comment: How result should be represented and what is n limit? For n > 13 there can be more than 2^65 coloring options--number that doesn't fit to any primitive type.

Answer (score 2):

I think your idea is right and a scan with window of 5x2 is the right approach.

I think the key is to keep track of a count for each value of the contents of the most recent two columns.  The count represents the total number of boards that end with those two columns.

There are 2^(5*2)=1024 choices of contents for these two columns.

Start by setting the count for each of these choices to 1.

Then for each new column try all ways of colouring it in and check which are legal.

You can then compute an updated list of counts for the window in the next position across.

When you have completed the scan you can simply add up all the final counts to get the total number of positions.

### OPTIMIZATION

For each new column we will always find the same set of legal patterns, so you can just work these out once and then save the resulting list of positions to update.

In fact the update is exactly equivalent to a matrix multiplication so you could use fast matrix exponentiation to compute the value for very large n.  (Probably not worth it if n is only up to 3000 as the matrix would be large.)

### WORKED EXAMPLE

Consider a simpler task where we have 2 rows and n columns and are trying to count the number of ways of colouring the board without having a pattern with two horizontally adjacent 1's.  For this problem we can use the same approach only with a 2 by 1 window.

There are 4 starting patterns, each with an initial count of 1:

```
0  0  1  1
0  1  0  1
```

For each of these we consider all ways of adding on the next column.

e.g. for the 1,0 column we consider:

```
10
00
```

this does not contain the pattern so we add 1 to the 0,0 output.

```
10
01
```

this does not contain the pattern so we add 1 to the 0,1 output.

```
11
00
```

this *does* contain the pattern so we continue.

```
11
01
```

this *does* contain the pattern so we continue.

So we have found 0,1 adds a count of 1 to 0,0 and 1,0.
Similarly, 1,0 adds a count of 1 to 0,0 and 0,1.
1,1 adds a count of 1 to 0,0
0,0 adds a count of 1 to 0,0 and 0,1 and 1,0 and 1,1

So overall after one step we have the following counts:

```
0 count of 4
0

0 count of 2
1

1 count of 2
0

1 count of 1
1
```

So if n was equal to 2, we add up all these numbers to find 4+2+2+1=9 possible ways of colouring a 2 by 2 board without adjacent ones.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm trying to go with this approach:

Let's build 2d array of size 1024x32. For each of 2x5 setting, there are 32 possibilities to add a third row to get 3x5 setting. I want to cache such results and then make 1024 iterations with backtracking through whole array.

It sounds really slow slow... No idea how to improve it. I liked your post, it says much about nature of that problem